# Where vscode save all the ENBF they need to colorize text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bnf, ebnf

To vscode (or any other editor), put color based on language semantics they need a description, this description I believe is an EBNF specification. How can i acess this information on vscode?
does vscode save on xml?
Where is the path to this files?

Comment: syntax highlighting is done with TextMate grammar files

Comment: TextMate specs are not BNF nor EBNF. They are a collection of types and regular expressions. Alternatively, some editors and extensions perform semantic highlighting using a language server. When asked by the editor, the server evaluates the syntax and semantic analysis in the usual way, but mostly using a hand-coded parser hack. If you are interested in grammars, [Antlr](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) has a large collection.